# replacing different words in a string multiple number of times

Tags: string, python-3.x

So i have a string that is some piece of html code ans some text,now i want to replace the `<br />` tag with something else and i do that successfully using 
`str.replace('word to be replaced','to be replaced with')`,but my question is how do i do that if i have multiple tags to replace in the same string

Now i have reffered to many questions on this site but one seem to help and not even the `re.sub()` method as there is a weird 'string buffer error'.
the code is as follows:

```
  rawnews=re.findall(r'<p class="newscaption">(.*?)</p>',str(respData))
  for news in rawnews:
     print(news.replace('<br />','')#to be done with more tags like <p> and <a href>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example? What is `str(respData)`?

Comment: It's the data I extract from the html page using requests

Comment: Do you want to replace `<br/>` tags  inside `<p>` tags, or you just want to remove arbitrary tags? Please provide example string and the corresponding expected output. Also, since you aready are using "requests", can't you use BeautifulSoup to get rid of unnecessary tags?